# Exporting a portfolio with pictures

Tags: images, export

I wonder if a kind soul could help, as I'm going crazy here. I just recently started using Wordpress, and created a website where I have a lot of portfolios. The images in the portfolios have been fully SEO optimized with tags, etc. So this is my question: I have created another website where I want to use some of the portfolios from the first website, but the thought of importing all the images and optimizing them again is putting me off, so is there a way to export the portfolios from the first website to the new one with the pictures included? I used the Wordpess export tool, but the .xml file has no pictures on it; it did import the portfolio, but without any pictures.

Kind Regards

Jorge

Comment: Have a look at [this link](http://mor10.com/wordpress-importer-not-importing-attachments-try-exporting-all-statuses/)

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Did you ever figure out how to get this to work?